# Is there a standard procedure to "invert" a multivariable function?

Tags: functions, real-numbers

I have a function $P(Q,x)$ ($P$ as a function of variables $Q$ and $x$) and I would instead like to known the function $Q(P,x)$ ($Q$ as a function of variables $P$ and $x$).

These functions are in general non-linear and quite complicated, but all variables and functions are real-valued.

Are there some standard procedures to solve these kinds of problems?

Comment: The inverse function theorem. Note that many proofs are actually constructive, in that it's possible to computationally approximate the inverse functions at particular points in practice.

Comment: You can think of the $x$ as a constant, so this is the same as finding an inverse of a single-variable function. You have an equation of the form $p=...$ that involves $q$, and you need to solve it for $q$ by rearranging it into the form $q=...$ with no $q$s on the right-hand side.

Comment: No. There is no "standard" method. Almost all multivariate functions aren't globally invertible, anyway.